# Variable which can hold any datatype in Java

Tags: java, android

I need a variable which can hold any datatype. It can be a `byte` or `String`. Is this possible in Java?  I know in Swift there is a datatype called `Any` which can do it.

Comment: The superclass of every class in java is ``java.lang.Object``. A variable of that type can hold any class instance, but no primitives (like ``byte``). But java's wrapper classes (like ``Byte``) are Objects.

Comment: how do you convert int to byte ?

Comment: You do explicit type casting. For example: `Byte b = (Byte) obj;` But you have to be careful when dealing with objects casting as it may throw ClassCastException 
 in case the object isn't really a Byte

Answer (score 3):

There is no "any" type in Java and there is no Java type that is compatible with both reference types and primitive types.

The best you can do is use `java.lang.Object` which can be used to hold any reference types, and convert primitive values to the corresponding wrapper type; e.g. convert an `int` value to an `Integer` value.  But once you have done that, you can't distinguish (for example) `int` and `Integer` values.

---

Of course, you could write a bunch of code that could convert just about any Java value to a byte array or a String ... and back.  But I suspect that's not what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The variable of type OBJECT which can hold any types of data type when passed as an argument. Even you can try for Genrics in java.

```
class Printer
{
    public  void printArray(Object[] a)
    {
        for(Object ob:a)
            System.out.println(ob);
    }  
}

public class Solution {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Printer myPrinter = new Printer();
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
        String[] stringArray = {"Hello", "World"};
        myPrinter.printArray(intArray);
        myPrinter.printArray(stringArray);
        int count = 0;
    }
}
```